# ¿Como agregar datos dinamicamente a un JSON? - PHP

Tags: php, json

Trato de agregar datos dinamicamente a un JSON utilizando `array_push()`, para ello tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
$roles = [];

for ($i=1; $i <= 5; $i++) { 
    $rol = array($i => 'Rol'.$i);
    array_push($roles, $rol);
}
$json [] = array('RolesCliente' => $roles);
echo(json_encode($json));
```

y el resultado es el siguiente:

> [{"RolesCliente":[{"1":"Rol1"},{"2":"Rol2"},{"3":"Rol3"},{"4":"Rol4"},{"5":"Rol5"}]}]

Desafortunadamente esto no es el resultado que buscaba, ya que al momento de leer el json en el lado del cliente utilizando android studio esto se complica, el resultado que busco es el siguiente:

> [{"RolesCliente":[{"1":"Rol1","2":"Rol2","3":"Rol3","4":"Rol4","5":"Rol5"}]}]

Y para leer el JSON en android lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
jsonArrayRolesCliente = jsonObject.getJSONArray("RolesCliente");
jsonObject = jsonArrayRolesCliente.getJSONObject(0);

for(int i = 1; i < jsonArrayRolesCliente.length()+1; i++){
   rolesClienteList.add(jsonObject.getString(String.valueOf(i)));
}
```

Y el error que me sale es:

> org.json.JSONException: No value for 2

Comment: el resultado que obtienes es correcto, que es lo que se te complica realmente?

Comment: Ya actualize el codigo, y si, el resultado que obtengo es correcto pero no es el que necesito porque al leerlo obtengo errores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En php esta bien la forma que creas el JSON
en android tienes que ver que tu respuesta completa es un JSONArray,dentro de ese JSONArray va un JSONObject

suponiendo que obtienes tu respuesta del servidor

```
 JSONArray jsonArray = response;

 JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.get(0) // obtienes el elemento que va dentro de tu respuesta

 //ahora sacamos el array de roles
  JSONArray jsonRoles =  jsonObject.getJSONArray("RolesCliente")

//ya tienes tu array de roles


for(int i = 1; i < jsonRoles.length();i++) {
  JSONObject rol = jsonRoles.getJSONObject(i); //obtenenes cada uno de los roles
 Log.I("rol",rol.getString(String.valueOf(i));
}
```

Comment: Funciona tu codigo si al `JSONObject rol = jsonRoles.getJSONObject(i);` le pones: `JSONObject rol = jsonRoles.getJSONObject(i-1);` y al for: `for(int i = 1; i <= jsonRoles.length();i++)`.

Comment: ese + 1 esta de mas, ya editol la variable i iniciar en 1, no hay necesidad de sumar, revisa nuevamente